# move_uploaded_file($tmpPath, $destPath); Returns False. Mac

Tags: php, macos, apache, unit-testing

```
return move_uploaded_file($tmpPath, $destPath);
```

Where

```
$destPath = "/Library/WebServer/Documents/root/media/tmp/catalog/650540b.jpg"
```

And

```
$tmpPath = "/Library/WebServer/Documents/root/tmp/640540b.jpg"
```

I chmodded both directories,

```
$_FILES['image_file']['tmp_name'] = "/Library/WebServer/Documents/superiorstore/tmp/640540b.jpg"
$_FILES['image_file']['name'] = "650540b.jpg"
```

But move_uploaded_file always returns false. I put the file in the tmp directory prior to running the code for testing on my local machine.

Comment: Is it maybe because in $tmpPath you're using a hypen instead of an equal sign to assign the string to the variable?

Comment: move_uploaded_file will only move the file if it was actually uploaded during the current request.  If you put a file somewhere manually, you can't use move_uploaded_file, instead use rename or move.

Comment: Are you actually posting it throw a form, or just test the command with a file placed in a directory (temp)?

Comment: I am not posting through a form.I am manually using a tmp folder. I thought I could atleast do that.

Comment: I am doing phpunit testing. How would I be able to get around that in  a test case.  I can't just change the method.

Answer (score 0):

I would like you to check those lines from [**`documentation`**](https://www.php.net/move_uploaded_file)

> - This function checks to ensure that the file designated by filename is a valid upload file (meaning that it was uploaded via PHP's HTTP POST upload mechanism). If the file is valid, it will be moved to the filename given by destination.
> - This sort of check is especially important if there is any chance that anything done with uploaded files could reveal their contents to the user, or even to other users on the same system.

My best bet is that your are trying to only move the file from a directory to another, and if so there is a command you might want to use as [**`rename()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php) but `move_uploaded_file()` will only works if the upload process has been done correctly. That's why you still get `false`.

Comment: well how would you be able to get around that issue in a test case ?

Comment: You need to setup a form and post the file as it is supposed to be